# How can i concat a variable with a string in vuejs template?

Tags: vue.js

I need to concat a string with the value of my variable i was trying this:

<el-tab-pane label="price {{cars.value}}"

but i am getting `"price {{cars.value}}"`

i want to show like this:

```
"price 3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using v-bind. And you don't need to use it **.value** in the template as VUE does that automatically for you. Try using like following:

```
<el-tab-pane v-bind:label="'price '+ cars"
```

For reference: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-bind